# android asmack private chat in MUC group

Tags: android, private, openfire, smack, chatroom

I am using asmack and openfire to develop group chat(MUC). Now I want to make a private chat within group occupants list like for example if the group has 10 contacts ,user can chat with only 6 contacts in the list while the message should not sent to remaining other 4 contacts.
Is it possible in asmack and openfire , if possible kindly suggest me the API.

Answer (score 0):

Why not creating another MUC and make it private.

Then, invite the selected contacts to join this room.

Hope this helps
Yaron